# Oracle ODBC SqlConnect() does not connect from remote machine

Tags: c#, database, oracle, odbc, pinvoke

I am using PInvoke to call the native ODBC API of the Oracle driver (sqora32.dll). When I run my code on the machine where the database is hosted, the connection works without any problems. But once I want to connect from a remote machine in the same local network, the connection fails.
SqlGetDiagRec returns the following message: "ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error" and I am not sure why this happens. When using SQLPlus from command line on the remote machine, I can connect to the database. But only when I use easy connect.

My aim is to connect to a Oracle database without having to configure any database specific data on the client for each connection (for example the tnsnames.ora).
In my test environment I have an Oracle 12C Standard Edition running on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Do you have any idea, why my remote connections fail? Am I missing something here? I have already tried to pass the serverName in different ways like

- [hostName]
- [hostName]/[serviceName]
- [hostName]:[port]/[serviceName]
- (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=[hostName])(Port=[port]))(CONNECT_DATA=(serviceName)))

and so on but nothing worked yet. I have also tried to directly pass the IP instead of the FQDN as host name but without any success.

Here is my connection code:

```
public void Connect(string serverName, string userName, string password)
    {
        // Allocate environment handle
        nSQLResults = OracleNative.SQLAllocHandle(ODBC32.SQL_HANDLE.ENV, ODBC32.SQL_HANDLE_NULL, out this.environmentHandle);

        // Set ODBC3 environment handle
        nSQLResults = OracleNative.SQLSetEnvAttr(environmentHandle, ODBC32.SQL_ATTR.ODBC_VERSION, ODBC32.SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);

        // Get connection handle
        nSQLResults = OracleNative.SQLAllocHandle(ODBC32.SQL_HANDLE.DBC, environmentHandle, out this.connectionHandle);

        // Open the connection
        nSQLResults = OracleNative.SQLConnect(connectionHandle, serverName, ODBC32.SQL_NTS, userName, ODBC32.SQL_NTS, password, ODBC32.SQL_NTS);

        if (nSQLResults == ODBC32.RetCode.ERROR)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Could not establish connection.");
        }
    }
```

And these are the native methods I use:

```
[DllImport("sqora32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern ODBC32.RetCode SQLAllocHandle(
    ODBC32.SQL_HANDLE HnadleType,
    IntPtr inputHandle,
    out IntPtr outputHandle
);

[DllImport("sqora32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern ODBC32.RetCode SQLSetEnvAttr(
    IntPtr EnvironmentHandle,
    ODBC32.SQL_ATTR Attribute,
    IntPtr ValuePtr,
    Int32 StringLength
);

[DllImport("sqora32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern ODBC32.RetCode SQLConnect(
    IntPtr ConnectionHandle,
    string ServerName,
    Int16 NameLength1,
    string Username,
    Int16 NameLength2,
    string Authentication,
    Int16 NameLength3
);
```

Comment: I had used Devart Oracle Connector with direct mode successfully. It allows me to connect from any machine in direct mode, without having to install Oracle client.

Comment: @Oscar thanks for the hint. But as I saw this one uses ADO.NET. But I forgot to say that the program will later run as a Universal Windows application which does not support ADO.NET.
*edit: Forget it. I wasn´t able to google correctly. I will give it a try!

Comment: @Oscar unfortunately the Devart Connector does not work as well. It shows the same error message.